# Slide columns from a given column in R

Tags: r

I was given some data that appear to be in a `veeeery` bad format, so I'm formatting them column-by-column in R

```
df <- read.table("path/to/file", sep = ' ', header = F, fill = T, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

When opening the file in RStudio, it looks like this

```
V1        V2         V3    V4          V5           V6 
column1   column2    NA    column3     column4      column5
```

How can I move the `first` row to the left so that I will get this:

```
V1        V2         V3          V4          V5 
column1   column2    column3     column4     column5
```

Comment: "formatting column-by-column"? How many rows do you have? Do you really have only five columns? Do you just want to remove NA values? Or do you want to delete whole columns?

Comment: Probably this can be addressed in the "reading the data" step - can you show the first few lines of your file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very efficient or elegant, but exactly what you are asking for (only the first row):

```
df <- read.csv(text = "column1 column2 NA column3 column4 column5", sep = " ", header = F, stringsAsFactors = F)
df
df[1, 3:5] <- df[1, 4:6]
df$V6 <- NULL                   # delete the last column
# Alternative: df[1, 6] <- NA   # just set the cell to NA
df
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you have multiple rows that are not aligned in a column. You can extract and align those columns and then rbind them with the rest of the dataset

My code:

```
require(dplyr)

df<-data.frame(row=LETTERS[1:4],
           V1=rep(1,4),
           V2=rep(2,4),
           V3=c("NA","3","NA","3"),
           V4=c("3","4","3","4"),
           V5=c("4","5","4","5"),
           V6=c("5","NA","5","NA"))
df

# Identify rows to shift
shift_rows <- which(with( df, df$V3=="NA"))

#Extract and shift the identified rows
dfshifted<- df  %>% "["(.,shift_rows,) %>% mutate(V3=V4,V4=V5,V5=V6)

# Extract rows requiring no shifting
dfunshifted<- df[-shift_rows,]

# Bind them
df<-rbind(dfshifted,dfunshifted,make.row.names = F)

# Order the rows
df<- df[order(df$row),]

df$V6<- NULL

df
```